# Trying to create finit sequences of numbers in python2: IndexError (beginner)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, debugging, index-error

edit: The initial problem is solved now, look at the bottom of the question; I have another problem.

I have a list, `s2` that its first element (`s[0]`) is a list of numbers with the length of `n` (defined by user input) and its elements are also defined by the user. What I want to do is to create n-1 more sequences of numbers as other elements of `s2`. Each of those sequences is made of the subtraction of the sequential elements in the previous sequence. (the right element - the left element) so the second sequence's length is n-1, the third: n-2 ... and the nth sequence's length (`s2[n-1]`'s) is 1.

```
for j in range(1, n):
    for k in range(0,n-j):
        s2[j].append(s2[j-1][k+1] - s2[j-1][k])
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]", line 9, in <module>
    s2[j].append(s2[j-1][k+1] - s2[j-1][k])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can you help me debug this?

edit:

```
n = int(raw_input())
s = raw_input()
s1 = [int(i) for i in s.split(" ")]
s2 = []
s2.append(s1)
for j in range(1, n):
    for k in range(0,n-j):
        s2[j].append(s2[j-1][k+1] - s2[j-1][k])
```

example input:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

ps: Can you suggest me another method to get the nth one faster than this? instead of creating all of these lists? (I want it to take less than 1 sec even when n is very big)

Comment: What you are using here is a `list` not an `array`. Arrays exist in python and are a completely different thing.

Comment: Please provide an example of input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize every `s2` element before trying to use it. Otherwise how would python know what type it is?

```
for j in range(1, n):
    s2.append(list())
    for k in range(0, n-j):
        s2[j].append(s2[j-1][k+1] - s2[j-1][k])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `s2[j]`, but haven't created it. Try something like this

```
for j in range(1, n):
    s2.append([]) 
    for k in range(0, n-j): 
        s2[j].append(s2[j-1][k+1] - s2[j-1][k])
```